# Mysql Metrics which needs Understanding

Tags: mysql

One of my websites showing the mysql connections as:

```
 Variable_name            | Value    |
+--------------------------+----------+
| Aborted_connects         | 52385    |
| Connections              | 48367050 |
| Max_used_connections     | 201      |
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0        |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0        |
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0        |
| Threads_connected        | 50
```

So i wanna know, my setting is often showing gateway issues, and sometimes internal error.

so how should i increase the max connections and what the above metrics actually mean?

Thanks

Comment: you can change `max_connections` variable by setting it to a higher number http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections 
for other variables meaning refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html

Comment: should i flush them or i need to update the max connections to somelimit like 500 etc

Comment: just set max connections to a higher number.

Comment: I had set the max xonnections to 500, but still doubtful of one question, what exactly means my Max_used_connections, is it use one time or it is the whole amount till the same has en online

Comment: It means at one point you have had 201 concurrent users on your MySQL server.